# Twilio outgoing call with call screening

Tags: twilio, phone-call

I need to make outgoing call with twilio and screen for human. In many cases, twilio starts playing the screening message before someone can answer the phone.

So by the time someone answers on the other end, the screening message gets finished (and starts in loop after few seconds) or they hear the intermediate message. Is there way to play the screening message only after someone answers the call on the other end?

Here is my TWIML for the call screening -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Pause>3</Pause>
  <Gather action="{{some_URL}}" timeout="10" numDigits="1">
    <Play>{{call_screening_message.wav}}</Play>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>{{some_URL}}</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to ensure a human has answered the call. The audio should not start playing until something has answered the line.

To tell if a human or a machine answered Twilio has some experimental features which you can read about here.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine